# JQuery UI a tag not styling as a button in Firefox and IE

Tags: jquery-ui, firefox

I am having a strange issue with trying to style a link as a JQuery UI button. It's showing up as a button in Chrome and as a link in Firefox and IE8.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery-ui-1.8.9.custom.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="test/css" href="stylesheet/jquery-ui-1.8.9.custom.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet/styles.css">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("a").button();
        });
    </script>
    <title>Introduction</title>
</head>
<body class="indexbody">
    <div class="indexwrapper">
        <div id="introduction">        
            <div class="btn">
                <a href="test.html" >link</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's the result in Firebug?  Do you see the UI values get set on the class attribute?  What have you tried so far?  In the famous words of Tom Cruise, "Help me help you".

Comment: Firefox: class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only"
Chrome: class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only"

Generated HTML is identical in Firefox and Chrome. In IE there are no ui-* classes applied.

Comment: In Chrome I see a green button (as expected). In Firefox and IE I see a link.

Comment: Just to confirm, in Firefox you do see the class attributes applied to the HTML, but the styles are just not rendering in the browser?  If so, I'm seeing the same thing.  What's odd is that the actual CSS does not appear in the CSS tab.  Can you confirm the CSS appears in your NET tab?  I'm thinking this may be something wrong in the CSS file maybe.

Comment: yes I can see the style attributes applied but it's not rendering as a button in Firefox. File seems ok...
yes I can't see style file in NET log either (Firefox) In Chrome I can see the style file in Resources

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like there is an easy to miss typo in your CSS link element.  The type attribute should be `text/css`, not `test/css`.

The `x` and `s` are just so close to each other.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
    href="stylesheet/jquery-ui-1.8.9.custom.css">
```

While Chrome adapted, the other browsers are more strict with their syntax.  Chrome follows the [Robustness Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robustness_principle).

Finally, the order in which you load the CSS or JavaScript does not appear to matter.  The link tag can come either before or after the script elements.

Comment: @Andrew - You're welcome.  It's too bad Firebug doesn't find stuff like that and report it.  My HTML Validator for Firefox extension didn't complain either.

Comment: I might give this HTML Validator a go, thanks for the tip. I really need to watch my typos :) Impressed that Chrome worked around this type and others failed. I usually test in Firefox then IE and finally in Chrome, I think I'll stick with this order for now.

Comment: @Andrew - My development team follows that methodology.  We all love Chrome but find it's easier to catch problems early if we test in IE and Firefox first.  On the other hand, I have seen some bugs that rear their ugly heads in Chrome but not Firefox or IE.

Answer (score 0):

CSS comes first to JS inclusion, that should solve your problem.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="test/css" href="stylesheet/jquery-ui-1.8.9.custom.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet/styles.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery-ui-1.8.9.custom.min.js"></script>
```